# QBO SDK PHP getting all deposits customer

Tags: quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I would like to know how to get all deposits of a target customer with the following SDK (https://github.com/intuit/QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK).

Is there an easier way than getting all deposits, then looping to extract the wanted customer's deposits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Official QBO answer:

> You can get complete deposit list by querying the “Query a deposit”
> API end point. If we use filter in query, then it may return incorrect
> results. Better you can iterate the response and add filter logic in
> your code and get specified